# Python XDR TCP stream

Tags: python, xdr

I have a C socket server who receive XDR data. I have wrote a C and a Java client. I am trying to write a Python client using `xdrlib`.

```
import xdrlib

p = xdrlib.Packer()
p.pack_int(5) 
p.pack_int(4)
p.pack_int(3)
data = p.get_buffer()
```

When i decode this via the server data are different. This is because data are encoded as to be read via a xdrmem decoder. (they do not have start and end of record).

Does anyone know if there is a library for python who support the creation of xdr records? In c this is done via `xdrrec_create` and in Java this is called `XdrTcpEncodingStream`.

Comment: Minimum packet length, packet block size. Need create packet pattern for global use. Every packet contained a block definition. Don't communicate without header definition.

Comment: sorry... can you rephrase your comment? i did not get what you explained...

Answer (score -2):

I mostly see `xdrlib` is the package mostly used. When you have processes that can be done in `C` or `Java`, You can just run them in c/java and use it in python by using and interface created by `Swig`. Let me know if my understanding doesn't suit the scenario.

Comment: well... i used Swig in the past but if I use the C library xdrrec_create uses different callbacks for retriving the data. I am afraid that this will not be so easy to map in python. 
I did not try to wrap around the Java version.
If I can find a Python module that suit my needs I prefer otherwise I think I will simply stick to java to write my client (or wrap the Java library in swig for python)

Comment: he is searching for a python module. Swig is always a solution but not what he is asking for